# How to include the ipywidgets interact code in my own function

Tags: python, widget, ipywidgets

For example, I define my own function "f":

```
def f(x):
    return x
```

and I want to make it interactable, so I wrote another function "F":

```
from ipywidgets import interact
def F():
    interact(f,x=10)
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas about how I can adjust my code?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your calling your function

```
def f(x):
    return x

def F():
    interact(f, x=10)

F()
```

will work. Since f is defined in a separate file

```
from MyFunctions import f

interact(f, x=10);
```

If you make changes to f then restart the kernel because "This will reset your notebook and remove all variables or methods you've defined"

Comment: Yes, Max. It will work directly in Jupyter. However, I am used to putting all my functions in a file named "MyFunctions.py" and import this file whenever I want to use a function in this file. It won't work that way.

Comment: If you have your f function defined in a separate file and have imported it with `from MyFunctions import f` try restarting the kernel.